# Is "all swans are white" equivalent to "if it is not white, then it is not a swan"?

Tags: logic

By equivalent I mean, each hypothesis can be deducted from the other.

Comment: Yes: "all swans are white” is "if it is a swan, then it is white".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

All swans are white:

```
∀x(Sx → Wx)
```

If it is not white then it is not a swan:

```
∀x(~Wx → ~Sx)
```

Generally, `p → q` is equivalent to `~q → ~p`. The latter is the [contrapositive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition) of the former. Similarly, the above two formulations are equivalent.

Comment: Why "generally"?

Comment: @gg.kaspersky `p → q` is a more general form, and `Sx → Wx` is a particular case, that's all.